# Bash script to kill Firefox and then re-launch it in fullscreen

Tags: bash, shell-script

So far, my code is as follows.

```
watch -n 1200 {
            ps -ef | grep firefox | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
            xdg-open https://google.com
            xdotool key F11
            }
```

I want this to kill firefox if it's running, then relaunch a certain URL (with google as a placeholder) and place the browser in fullscreen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would start by simplifying to pkill firefox... what is going wrong with what you have?

Comment: What is happening that you are not expecting?